# Removing all strings in a list that are of x length

Tags: python, string, list

One of my revision practices involves creating a function that removes all strings that has the highest string length in a list.

Expected Output:

```
words_list = ['fish', 'barrel', 'like', 'shooting', 'sand', 'bank']
print(remove_long_words(words_list))
['fish', 'barrel', 'like', 'sand', 'bank']
```

Code so far:

```
def remove_long_words(words_list):
    length_long = get_longest_string_length(words_list)
    
    for ele in words_list:
        if len(ele) == length_long:
            #???
            words_list.pop(???)
    
    return words_list
```

I first made a function that returns the length of the longest string in the list, then used a for loop to iterate through every element in the list, and from there used an if statement to see if the length of the element is equal to the longest string length. I'm having trouble going on from there, how do I use the .pop method to remove the right elements from the list?

Do I have to convert the list to a string then use .find to find the index position of the element that meets the required length? And how would I make it that it finds all occurrences, not just the first one it finds.

Comment: Better not to use `pop()` while iterating over the same list. You can create a copy of the list and iterate over that or else create a new list as output

Comment: @James, `pop` requires `index` to be passed

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 5):

Using a list comprehension:

```py
words_list = ['fish', 'barrel', 'like', 'shooting', 'sand', 'bank']
max_len = len(max(words_list, key=len))
output = [x for x in words_list if len(x) != max_len]
print(output)  # ['fish', 'barrel', 'like', 'sand', 'bank']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Lambda function

```
words_list = ['fish', 'barrel', 'like', 'shooting', 'sand', 'bank']
```

```
list(filter(lambda x,m=max(map(len, words_list)):len(x)!=m, words_list))
```

**Output**

```
['fish', 'barrel', 'like', 'sand', 'bank']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a one-liner that you could use, but I find this easier to understand.

```
words_list = ['fish', 'barrel', 'like', 'shooting', 'sand', 'bank']
max = max(words_list, key=len)
list = []
for word in words_list:
    if len(word) < max:
        list.append(word)
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're explicitly asking about `list.pop`
You can first create masking for each item based on the length, and iterate through the index of this mask list and pop the elements:

```py
maxLen = len(max(words_list))
mask = [len(x) == maxLen for x in words_list]

for i in reversed(range(len(mask))):
    if mask[i]:
        words_list.pop(i)
```

Make sure you pop in reversed order of index to avoid `IndexError`

**OUTPUT**

```py
['fish', 'barrel', 'like', 'sand', 'bank']
```